SwiftUI observe changes in computed property
I have the following computed property (currentTime) in my Observable class which I want to observe in SwiftUI view. Problem is changes in the property are not published as it does not rely on stored properties. I have been using Combine publishers previously to solve the issue but I wonder if there is a better way to solve this in the new observation framework introduced in iOS 17?
   @available(iOS 17.0, *)
   @Observable
    class VideoPlayerVM {
    private(set) public var player: AVPlayer = AVPlayer()


    var currentTime:CMTime {
        let time = self.player?.currentItem?.currentTime()

        if time.isValid {
           return time
        }

        return .invalid
    }

  }


How did you use Combine previously? You should still be able to do that with @Observable. For this specific case, I would suggest using addPeriodicTimeObserver.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback/monitoring_playback_progress_in_your_app/

I read that Observation framework deprecates Combine, so thats the reason for asking a question, whether we could observe it using only observation framework without Combine?

Whatever Combine publisher you were using before should also work with @Observable. You just need to sink that publisher and assign its values to a stored property in the @Observable class.
That said, I'm not sure why you'd be using a Combine publisher in the first place, if you want to observe the current time of an AVPlayer. There is a dedicated method, addPeriodicTimeObserver, that allows you to observe the current time at regular intervals.
You can use it like this:
@Observable
@MainActor
class VideoPlayerVM {
    private(set) public var player: AVPlayer = AVPlayer()
    
    
    var currentTime: CMTime = .zero
    private var observation: Any?
    
    func startObservingCurrentTime() {
        guard observation == nil else { return }
        observation = player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(
            forInterval: .init(
                seconds: 0.5,
                preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC)
            ),
            queue: nil
        ) { time in
            MainActor.assumeIsolated {
                self.currentTime = time
            }
        }
    }
    
    func stopObservingCurrentTime() {
        if let observation {
            player.removeTimeObserver(observation)
            observation = nil
        }
    }
}

You should call stopObservingCurrentTime in onDisappear of the view that owns the VideoPlayerVM.
Note that I used MainActor.assumeIsolated in the closure for addPeriodicTimeObserver. This is safe because queue: nil means that the closure will be called on the main dispatch queue, which is the serial executor of the main actor.

So we need to have a stored property for observation, that's the only possibility.

@DeepakSharma Not necessarily, but this is the most convenient for this particular case. You can manually call access and withMutation in a computed property too. See for example my answer here.

@DeepakSharma I just tried it out and indeed, calling access (in the getter) and withMutation (in the closure to addPeriodicTimeObserver) manually also works, but why manually write the calls that the macro would have generated if you changed it to a stored property? :)

I had a different VM called EditingVM for managing video editing UI. I was sharing variables between PlayerVM and EditingVM (such as AVPlayer to access its time and duration). But now I stored an instance of PlayerVM in EditingVM and access player properties through PlayerVM. It works great, but I know I am nesting View Models.
